# How to read web.config

Tags: custom, web

I want to read username and password from web.config file.

Username,password will be stored in custom tags of web.config file of sharepoint project.

Answer (score 2):

Ouch - don't do this! Use the [Secure Store Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee806889.aspx) to map user credentials. It is designed to store and map credentials in a very secure way.

Answer (score 0):

its simple, check this out on msdn it explains it really simply:

but this shouldnt store a user ID/Password ;) that should be kept in AD(active Directory)

if its for a webpart to connect like to K2 server or SQL then its fine:

reading connection string:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178411

Read app settings from web.config
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/610xe886.aspx